# Significance of remaining Einstein equations in the TOV solution

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In looking for a metric of a relativistic star, we typically employ the Einstein field equations
$$
G_{\mu\nu} = 8 \pi T_{\mu\nu} 
$$

with the assumption of a perfect, static fluid $u^{\mu}$ with a corresponding energy-momentum tensor, as well as a metric form that takes advantage of the spacetime symmetries:
$$
g =- e^{2\phi}dt^2  + e^{2\lambda} dr^2 + r^2 d\theta^2 + r^2 \sin^2\theta d\varphi^2.
$$
Additionally, we make use of the conservation equations $\nabla_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu}=0$, where due to the symmetries actually only the orthogonal part (projected perpendicular to $u^{\mu}$ with $h_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu} + u_{\mu}u_{\nu}$), and its $\mu=r$ component gives a non-trivial equation.

Furthermore, out of the Einstein equations, the final TOV equations use only $\mu = t, r$ components, whereas the $\theta,\phi$ are linearly dependent, so just one of them can be used. Here comes my question:

What is the significance of $G_{\theta\theta}=8\pi T_{\theta\theta}$? When computed, it provides a 2-nd order equation on $\phi(r)$. It surely is then redundant, since we already have a 1-st order equation on that metric function.
However, I cannot prove that it is linearly dependent on all the other equations, and hence, can be excluded from the set. Could someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see how the $\theta\theta$ equation is implied by the $tt$ and $rr$ equations, define
$$
\mathcal{E}^{\mu \nu} = G^{\mu \nu} - 8 \pi T^{\mu \nu}
$$
The Einstein equation is then just the requirement that all of the components of $\mathcal{E}^{\mu \nu} = 0$.

However, because of the underlying symmetry of the system, we only need to require that a subset of these components vanish, and the rest will automatically vanish.  This comes in two parts.  The more obvious part is that $\mathcal{E}^{\phi \phi} = 0$ if and only if $\mathcal{E}^{\theta \theta} = 0$ due to the spherical symmetry of the spacetime.<sup>1</sup>

The more subtle symmetry in the EOMs is due to diffeomorphism invariance, which (*cf.* Appendix E of Wald) leads to the geometric identity
$$
\nabla_{\mu} \mathcal{E}^{\mu \nu} = 0. \tag{1}
$$
which will be satisfied regardless of whether $\mathcal{E}^{\mu \nu} = 0$.
In particular, writing out the $\nu = r$ component of this equation in terms of partial derivatives and (non-vanishing) Christoffel symbols implies that
$$
\partial_{\mu} \mathcal{E}^{rr}+ \Gamma^\mu {}_{\mu r} \mathcal{E}^{rr} + \Gamma^{r} {}_{tt} \mathcal{E}^{tt} + \Gamma^{r} {}_{rr} \mathcal{E}^{rr} + \Gamma^{r} {}_{\theta \theta} \mathcal{E}^{\theta \theta} + \Gamma^{r} {}_{\phi \phi} \mathcal{E}^{\phi \phi} = 0. \tag{2}
$$
From (2), you can show which combinations of $\mathcal{E}^{tt}$ and $\mathcal{E}^{rr}$ are proportional to $\mathcal{E}^{\theta \theta}$.  In particular, we can draw the following conclusion:

> If $\mathcal{E}^{tt} = 0$ and $\mathcal{E}^{rr} = 0$, then $\mathcal{E}^{\theta \theta} = 0$.

Alternately, it is also true that

> If $\mathcal{E}^{\theta \theta} = 0$ and $\mathcal{E}^{rr} = 0$, then $\mathcal{E}^{tt} = 0$.

However, the fact that (2) contains a radial derivative of $\mathcal{E}^{rr}$ means that

> $\mathcal{E}^{tt} = \mathcal{E}^{\theta \theta} = 0$ does **not** necessarily imply that $\mathcal{E}^{rr} = 0$.

Rather, it implies that $\partial_r \mathcal{E}^{rr} + f(r) \mathcal{E}^{rr} = 0$ for some function $f(r)$;  and there will in general exist non-trivial solutions to this ODE.

---

<sup>1</sup> Specifically, $\mathcal{E}^{\phi \phi} = \mathcal{E}^{\theta \theta}/\sin^2 \theta$.  This can be seen by constructing an orthonormal basis for the spherical components and demanding that the components in this basis be equal via symmetry.  It can also be seen by computing $\nu = \theta$ or $\nu = \phi$ components of Eq. (1).

Comment: Thank you for the extensive explanation. This certainly proves it in a formal way.

In a brute-force manner, does this mean that in principle I should be able to plug in the obtained, classical TOV equations into the LHS $\mathcal{E}^{\theta\theta}=0$ and obtain a tautological $0=0$?

Comment: @K.T.:  Yes, Eq. (2) tells you the combination of $\mathcal{E}^{tt}$, $\mathcal{E}^{rr}$, and $\partial_r \mathcal{E}^{rr}$ that's necessary to accomplish that tautology via brute force. (You'll also need to eliminate $\mathcal{E}^{\phi \phi}$ in terms of $\mathcal{E}^{\theta \theta}$, but it should be relatively obvious how these two components are related.)

Comment: Also note that you'll need to use the hydrostatic equilibrium equation as one of your "tools" in this brute-force tautology, because that equation is necessary to have $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu \nu} = 0$.